# How to bulkify an email alert in a flow?

Tags: visual-workflow

I got a flow that tries to match a record to another record. If the flow fails to find a mapping, I'd like to send out an email with the records that failed to do the mapping.

However, if I bulk insert a few records with non-matching records, I'd like to send out *one* email with all the failed mappings and not one email for each failed mapping. The current flow will send out an email for each mapping that failed.

Is it possible to bulkify the failed mappings and add them to a collection variable and only send out one email, instead of multiple emails?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The Action itself is bulkified, in the sense that all emails generated are sent at the same time. If you want to detect a situation where it would be useful to send all the results in a single email, use an Apex Action instead. This will involve the use of [InvocableMethod](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_annotation_InvocableMethod.htm). In Apex, all interviews that block at the same Apex Action will have their inputs arranged in a way that you can see all matching data.

Here's a rough example on how you'd write this.

```
@InvocableMethod(description='Send email for non-matching product Ids')
public static void sendEmail(List<Id> productIds) {
  Messaging.SingleEmailMessage message = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
  message.setTargetObjectId(UserInfo.getUserId()); // send to user
  message.setSaveAsActivityFlag(false); // Cannot save this as a Task
  message.setSubject('Non-matching product Ids');
  message.setBody(generateEmailBody(productIds)); // abstracted
  Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.Email[] { message }); // send email
}
```

Comment: Yeah I think I meant that I want to send every "error" in a single email rather than as separate emails. Would it not be possible to do that directly from the flow?

Answer (score 0):

Create a text variable.
Add a line of text for each error.
Send one email at the end with the text variable in the body.